# Converting edgelist to graph doesn't keep values

Tags: r, graph, weighted-graph, edge-list

I trying to convert an an edgelist to a weighted graph (i.e. keeping the values in the edgelist). Here is my edgelist:

```
Reporter.Countries Partner.Countries                 Year   Value
 1 Afghanistan        Canada                           2017       0 
 2 Afghanistan        Pakistan                         2015       2 
 3 Afghanistan        Slovakia                         2018       0 
 4 Albania            Iceland                          2017       0 
 5 Algeria            Senegal                          2017       0 
 6 Argentina          Bangladesh                       2014. 112942 
 7 Argentina          Belgium                          2016.      0 
 8 Argentina          Bolivia (Plurinational State of) 2016    7556 
 9 Argentina          Brazil                           2016     411.
10 Argentina          Canada                           2016.    364.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
#import data and average years
soybean <- read.csv("soybean.csv")

library(dplyr)
soybean <- soybean %>%
  group_by(Reporter.Countries, Partner.Countries) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean))

#make edgelist
edgelist <- soybean %>%
  select(Reporter.Countries, Partner.Countries, Year, Value)

edgelist$"Value" <- as.numeric(edgelist$"Value")

#converting to graph
g <- graph.data.frame(edgelist, directed=FALSE)

g <- set_edge_attr(g, "Value", value= edgelist$Value)

get.adjacency(g, type="both", attr="Value")

write.csv(as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)), file = "importedsoybean.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

But my adjacency matrix ends up with 1's and 2's instead of the values in the edgelist.

It looks like this:

```
Afghanistan                      . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 2 .
Albania                          . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
Algeria                          . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
Argentina                        . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . 2 . . 2 . . . . . .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="Reporter.Countries Partner.Countries Year Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1          Afghanistan         Canada          2017         0  
2          Afghanistan         Pakistan          2015         2  
3          Afghanistan         Slovakia          2018         0  
4          Albania        Iceland          2017         0  
5          Algeria         Senegal          2017         0  
6          Argentina             Bangladesh          2014         112942  
")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)

g <- set_edge_attr(g, "Value", value= edgelist$Value)

get.adjacency(g, type="both", attr="Value")

get.adjacency(g)

write.csv(as.matrix(get.adjacency(g)), file = "importedsoybeantext.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please make sure to share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) otherwise it's difficult to copy/paste to run and test the code. How are you creating this adjacency matrix? Are you using `as_adjacency_matrix`? are you setting the `attr=` parameter?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for not being clear! I have added two lines of code where I use as.matrix get.adjacency(g, type="both", attr="Value") and then write the csv. It may also be that the error is happening when I try to write the file. I am somewhat new to r so I am struggling a bit with creating a reproducible example, but will try to fix it somehow.

Comment: Have now included a reproducible example!

Comment: With your example `as.matrix(get.adjacency(g, type="both", attr="Value"))` seems to work just fine. It uses the values of "Value" in the matrix. Is that not what you want?

Comment: The data contain values 0,2,112942, etc. These are the ones I would like to have in the matrix. For me, the code prints the csv as binary, only including 1's (and in my full code it prints with 1's and 2's).

Comment: Really? That’s what you get when you run the exact code you shared in the reproducible example? What version if igraph are you using?

Comment: Apparently 1.2.5. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by:

```
f <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g, type="both", attr="Value"))

write.csv(f, file = "importedsoybean.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```